# Typeorm Get full tree and relationships

Tags: orm, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I've currently got a closure-Table structure entity called Units.

A unit can have a child of a different unit (Imagine a Platoon can have many squads)

A unit can have a many to many relation with Members as many members can be a unit and a unit can be in many members.

I want to display the full tree and relation. What do i do as at the moment i can just get the tree with all the children but no relations or vise versa

Comment: Ive realised there was an update two weeks ago which added the functionality i needed, ignore this going to close

Answer (score 1):

const treeCategoriesWithRelations = await repository.findTrees({ relations: ["sites"] });
// automatically joins the sites relation

Make sure your up to date with Typeorm :)